# htaccess file serve programming

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am hosting videos mostly for non-smart phones, but for smart phones I want to give better quality videos.  The way I am doing it right now is detecting user agent with htaccess file since most of the non-smart phones ignored javascript and php.  My problem is that I have one htaccess file for each video since I don't know what video people are trying to watch.  Is there a better way to do this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a sensible, generalised file/folder structure that allows you to apply generalised rewrite rules. E.g.:

```
videos/
    low/
        abc.mp4
        def.mp4
        ...
    high/
        abc.mp4
        def.mp4
        ...
```

With URLs like:

```
example.com/videos/abc.mp4
```

With rewrite rules like:

```
RewriteCond <is mobile user>
RewriteRule videos/(.*) videos/high/$1 [L]

RewriteRule videos/(.*) videos/low/$1
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.  This is what I was looking for.  I don't understand the code very well but I'll give it a try right now! Thanks.

Comment: deceze, I have the htaccess in the videos folder and the link I am writing like: www.mysite.com/videos/video1.mp4  but it says file not found

Comment: Ok, I've trying different combination of this and for some reason it is not redirecting if I don't put the file name on the htaccess file.  Nice explanation by the way.

Comment: I got it to work.  I just had to put RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mywebsite.com/videos/high/$1, so I'll take it as a correct answer.